# (Why) are standard errors from nnet::multinom scale dependent?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial, standard-error, nnet

I have noticed that when I increase the scale of a predictor in a `multinom()` model (function is from `nnet` R package) the standard errors of other predictors and the intercept approach 0. Can someone tell my why that is? Feel like I'm overlooking something trivial here.

**EDIT:** 
To be clear, it is obvious to my why the coefficient and SE for the rescaled predictor (`speed`) would change. What I don't get is why the coefficient for the other predictor (`colorRed`) would remain the same while its SE changes to 0.

```
library(nnet)

# Make data
data("cars")
cars$color = sample(c("Blue", "Red"), nrow(cars), replace = T)
cars$used = sample(c(T, F), nrow(cars), replace = T)

# Normal model
car_model <- multinom(used ~ color + speed, data = cars, maxit=500)
round(summary(car_model)$coefficients,3)
round(summary(car_model)$standard.errors,3)
```

> ```
> round(summary(car_model)$coefficients,3)
> (Intercept)    colorRed       speed 
>      -2.216       0.054       0.136 
> round(summary(car_model)$standard.errors,3)
> (Intercept)    colorRed       speed 
>       1.060       0.607       0.062
> ```

```
# Rescale speed model
cars$speed = cars$speed*1000
car_model <- multinom(used ~ color + speed, data = cars, maxit=500)
round(summary(car_model)$coefficients,3)
round(summary(car_model)$standard.errors,3)
```

> ```
> (Intercept)    colorRed       speed 
>      -2.216       0.054       0.000 
> (Intercept)    colorRed       speed 
>           0           0           0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In a multinomial model, the coefficient associated with a continuous independent variable (like `speed`) represents the change in the dependent associated with a unit change in the predictor.  So scale changes in the predictor are reflected inversely in the value of the associated coefficient (and its standard error).  So when you multiply speed by 1000, I would expect the coefficient to be reduced by 1000.  So you initial coefficient of 0.136 would be come 0.000136.  Your summary is rounded to 3dp, so the new coefficient appears as 0.000.

Factors are unaffected by this because they are not "numeric" in the sense that continuous variables are.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, either I don't understand your answer or it doesn't answer my question. I should clarify: it is obvious to my why the coefficient and also the standard error for the rescaled predictor (```speed``` in this case) would change. What I do not get is how the coefficient for the other predictor (```colorRed``` in this case) remains the same (```.054```) but it's SE changes to ```0```. Am I missing something?